# Package 'dotnet-sdk-7.0' has no installation candidate on Xubuntu / Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, xubuntu

I followed the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2204-microsoft-package-feed) to install .NET 7 SDK after having installed .NET 6 SDK from the Ubuntu feed.

```bash
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-7.0` results in this error:

```bash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package dotnet-sdk-7.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dotnet-sdk-7.0' has no installation candidate
```

`sudo apt show dotnet-sdk-7.0 -a` results in this:

```
Package: dotnet-sdk-7.0
Version: 7.0.102-1
Priority: standard
Section: devel
Maintainer: Microsoft <dotnetcore@microsoft.com>
Installed-Size: 358 MB
Depends: aspnetcore-targeting-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.2), netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1 (>= 2.1.0), dotnet-apphost-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.2), dotnet-runtime-7.0 (>= 7.0.2), dotnet-targeting-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.2), aspnetcore-runtime-7.0 (>= 7.0.2)
Homepage: https://github.com/dotnet/core
Download-Size: 90,6 MB
APT-Sources: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: Microsoft .NET SDK 7.0.102
 .NET is a development platform that you can use to build command-line applications, microservices and modern websites. It is open source, cross-platform and is supported by Microsoft. We hope you enjoy using it! If you do, please consider joining the active community of developers that are contributing to the project on GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/core). We happily accept issues and PRs.

Package: dotnet-sdk-7.0
Version: 7.0.101-1
Priority: standard
Section: devel
Maintainer: Microsoft <dotnetcore@microsoft.com>
Installed-Size: 358 MB
Depends: aspnetcore-targeting-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.1), netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1 (>= 2.1.0), dotnet-apphost-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.1), dotnet-runtime-7.0 (>= 7.0.1), dotnet-targeting-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.1), aspnetcore-runtime-7.0 (>= 7.0.1)
Homepage: https://github.com/dotnet/core
Download-Size: 90,6 MB
APT-Sources: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: Microsoft .NET SDK 7.0.101
 .NET is a development platform that you can use to build command-line applications, microservices and modern websites. It is open source, cross-platform and is supported by Microsoft. We hope you enjoy using it! If you do, please consider joining the active community of developers that are contributing to the project on GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/core). We happily accept issues and PRs.

Package: dotnet-sdk-7.0
Version: 7.0.100-1
Priority: standard
Section: devel
Maintainer: Microsoft <dotnetcore@microsoft.com>
Installed-Size: 352 MB
Depends: aspnetcore-targeting-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.0), netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1 (>= 2.1.0), dotnet-apphost-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.0), dotnet-runtime-7.0 (>= 7.0.0), dotnet-targeting-pack-7.0 (>= 7.0.0), aspnetcore-runtime-7.0 (>= 7.0.0)
Homepage: https://github.com/dotnet/core
Download-Size: 88,4 MB
APT-Sources: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: Microsoft .NET SDK 7.0.100
 .NET is a development platform that you can use to build command-line applications, microservices and modern websites. It is open source, cross-platform and is supported by Microsoft. We hope you enjoy using it! If you do, please consider joining the active community of developers that are contributing to the project on GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/core). We happily accept issues and PRs.
```

Also tried `apt-get upgrade`

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list` contains this:

```
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy main
```

`apt policy dotnet-sdk-7.0` shows:

```
dotnet-sdk-7.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     7.0.102-1 -10
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages
     7.0.101-1 -10
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages
     7.0.100-1 -10
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

---

I could get the .NET 7 SDK installation working by adding the file `/etc/apt/preferences` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup#solutions):

```bash
Package: dotnet-sdk-7.0
Pin: origin "packages.microsoft.com"
Pin-Priority: 999
```

But .NET 6 SDK stopped working.

Comment: How I fixed the broken installation: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/fixing-my-bricked-dotnet-sdk-6-installation-on-xubuntu-ubuntu-after-dotnet-7-sdk-installation/